# Python subclass of abstract baseclass shows type error

Tags: python, typing, pylance

pylance gives an type error while the types of the variables are defined. Below a small example which shows the structure of the code and gives also the error:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generator, Any


@dataclass
class Base(ABC):
    data: list[str | int]

    def __iter__(self) -> Generator[str | int, Any, None]:
        for xin self.data:
            yield x

    def __getitem__(self, key) -> str | int:
        return self.data[key]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.data)

    @abstractmethod
    def some_general_function(self) -> None:
        pass


class Test1(Base):
    data: list[str]

    def some_general_function(self) -> None:
        print("General function from list with strings")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test1(['a', 'b', 'abc'])
    for ele in test:
        print(ele.capitalize)
```

The error is on the last line, the error says that the function `.capitalize` is not available for the type `int`.

In the implementation of the class (`Test1`) it is defined that the list data consist of elements with type `str`.

Also when this is tested in a `__post_init__` method in the `Test1` class the error still exists.

```
class Test1(Base):
    data: list[str]

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), self.data)):
            raise TypeError("data should be a `str`")
```

The only solution is to rewrite the `__iter__` of the baseclass, since the type hint there says that the generator can be a `str` and an `int`.

Is it possible to only rewrite the the return type (or yield type) of a function without rewriting the function itself?

Comment: What about just `str(ele).capitalize` ?

Comment: Because that would be double, since it is already known that the list should contain `str` elements. The code also works just fine, it is only in de editor (pylance) a problem.

Comment: I think you definitely need to redefine the function in the subclass. Similar to typed languages with function overloading. Or use something like this https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

Comment: @Codist because in the real example there is a second class from `Base` where the list will have elements of only `int` types. (the baseclass is there to be reused, otherwise there is also no need for the abstraction into a baseclass).

Comment: There is no narrowing by `any` or `all`. Your check is opaque for the type checker. If you add this check to `__post_init__`, it's even further from realistically possible inference. Make your class generic to say "data type may be narrowed in the subclass": https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=c563c9e1b4f072b3435b30d7e0c7675e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `TypeVar` and `Generic` from the library `typing` it is possible to adjust the code so it returns what one wants.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generator, Any, TypeVar, Generic


_T = TypeVar("_T")

@dataclass
class Base(ABC, Generic[_T]):
    data: list[_T]

    def __iter__(self) -> Generator[_T, Any, None]:
        for x in self.data:
            yield x

    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> _T:
        return self.data[key]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.data)

    @abstractmethod
    def some_general_function(self) -> None:
        pass


class Test1(Base[str]):
    def some_general_function(self) -> None:
        print("General function from list with strings")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test1(['a', 'b', 'abc'])
    for ele in test:
        print(ele.capitalize())
```

An explanation about `TypeVar` can be found here: https://dev.to/decorator_factory/typevars-explained-hmo

And the `Generic` parameter is explained here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html